# Get a part of the current path

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, directory, delimiter

I would like to get a part of the current directory where my batch script is from.

The location is something like this : Y:\abc\def\ghi\jkl\script.bat

I just want to keep what's after Y:\abc\def\  (that is \ghi\jkl)

How to do this ?

I'm using the code below for getting the full path but how to make a delimitation ?

```
for /f %%a in ("%CD%") do set CURR=%%a
echo %CURR%
```

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: what exactly is the rule? make it clearer so the question won't get closed as off-topic.

Comment: The current directory is not the same as the script directory.  It can be different.  The script path can be accessed by using the command line arguments.  `%~dp0` would be the location of the script.

Comment: I meant the script directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your stated "directory where my batch script is from", the following should suffice, *(the last line is added for demonstration purposes, please change it as necessary)*:

```batch-file
@Set "x=%~dp0"&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@Set "i=0"&Set "x!i!=%x:\="&Set /A i+=1&Set "x!i!=%"
@Set /A i-=1,y=i-1
@If %i% Lss 1 (Set "z=%x0%\")Else (If %i% Equ 1 (Set "z=%x0%\%x1%"
        )Else Set "z=!x%y%!\!x%i%!")
@EndLocal&Set "y=%z%"
@Echo %x% becomes %y%&Pause
```

I have made it so that if the scripts directory isn't deep enough, the full path will still be output.

If you want to use the current directory instead of the scripts location, change `%~dp0` on line `1` to `%__CD__%` or `%CD%\` as needed.

Comment: Can we start from a known folder name (which will remain unchanged) in the script path instead of starting from the beginning of the path ?

Comment: @Cospuser, you can start wherever you like, but not in this question. I have provided an answer based upon your question at the time of answering, _and I wasn't the first to do so!_ If you have a completely different question, you should deal with this one, before creating a new question. My script will not be modified, it works for the exact specifications you provided, and I'm not changing it now!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that maybe you could put the section to be cut inside a txt file and then manipulate the string from the loop in the file, like this:

```
echo %cd% > path.txt

for /f "tokens=3,* delims=\" %%a in (path.txt) do echo %%b
```

Determining the depth with the argument `tokens=3` with the delimiter character being `"\"`.

Comment: `echo %cd% > path.txt` has too many vulnerabilities. Try `>path.txt echo(%__CD__:~0,-1%` instead

Comment: can we delimit starting a folder name in the script path instead of sarting from the beginning of the path ?

Comment: in other words, is it possible to put more than one character to the delims parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "reversed="
set "fromdir=%~dp0"

for %%A in ("%fromdir:\=" "%") do call set "reversed=%%~A\%%reversed%%"
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=\" %%A in ("%reversed%") do set "result=\%%B\%%A"

echo %result%
pause
```

If the path segments can be reversed, then getting the last 2 segments is a known number for setting the tokens option of `1-2` as they would become the 1st 2 segments. The 1st `for` loop does the reversing. The 2nd `for` loop gets the 1st 2 tokens and is set to `result` in reverse order, which is the original order.

The `fromdir` is set for the script directory `%~dp0`, though it can be set with `%cd%` if is wanted.

View `set /?` for how `"%fromdir:\=" "%"` does replacement of `\` with `" "` so that the path segments become individual arguments i.e. `"C:\dir1\dir2\dir3"` becomes `"C:" "dir1" "dir2" "dir3"`.

Comment: How I can define from which a folder name in the path (that will always remains the same) I should keep everything after because let's admit that in the future, the path will be lengthened or shortened, it will be necessary to edit the code ?

Comment: Edit the script not needed. `%~dp0` value is the script directory. If you move the script to another location, `%~dp0` value changes to the new location. So you do not need to change it. If a fixed path of `\ghi\jkl` is needed, then move that as well and then I would have to wonder what point of the question posted as the path of the 2 last path segments is known. If you just want to access files relative to the script i.e. `\ghi\file.txt`, then you could just use `%~dp0..\file.txt` as `..` is up 1 directory from the script directory, `..\..` is up 2 directories etc.